# Close Excel workbook without prompt to save using php or js

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way to close excel workbook without prompt using PHP or JavaScript in `.php` file?
I use data from excel on the website and when refreshing the website I have to close prompt everytime.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried several php commands but none of them worked, I also tried to put VBA macro insine my excel workbook but it still prompts if I want to exit without changes

Comment: Why would you expect a PHP command (or javascript) to work if MS Excel is prompting for save?

Comment: Because I open it with PHP and still even though I had VBA code not to prompt it still asked me to

Comment: *I open it with `COM` command which is in PHP

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to close Excel (once opened automatically through a download of a .xls/.csv) on your local machine from a remote server? If this is the case then the answer is below.

No!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing part of the PHP code to close the workbook and staying with just VBA as a macro in the workbook itself